# Strange Makefile, need explanations

Tags: android, c++, makefile, compiler-errors, linux-kernel

I'm trying to compile a kernel but can't figure out how its Makefile work : https://github.com/LineageOS/android_kernel_sony_msm8994/blob/cm-14.1/scripts/Makefile.build

As I have this error when building : [Build of a custom Linux/Android/LineageOS kernel in C doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64848984/build-of-a-custom-linux-android-lineageos-kernel-in-c-doesnt-work) , I'm for now trying to understand up until the line 44.

1. Why are there several Makefile with extensions like `.build` `.clean` etc rather than these actions being "targets" within the main Makefile?
2. How can I figure out what the very first `$(obj)` var refers to ?
3. Is the mathematical syntax `:=` "equals by definition" instead of `=` specific to the developper? I do saw this on mathematics notes or symbolic languages such as Wolfram/Mathematica if I'm right, but never within a program.
4. Why does `PHONY :=` is a variable and not a "type of action" as in the doc ? It should be written `.PHONY:` as on the very last line of the file. I didn't get this trick.
5. Why are there 2 underscores before `__build` the value of `PHONY` ?

By thanking you for your precisions

Comment: Too many questions in the single question post. Note, that on Stack Overflow we expect the question to be about a **single problem**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because the person who wrote the makefile wanted to break those out into separate files.  Maybe they're included in multiple other files, or they just wanted the top-level makefile to be more clean to read.
2. You can run make with the `-p` option and it will print all the values of all the variables in the makefile.
3. I don't quite understand the question: the `:=` operator in a makefile is used for simply-expanded variable assignments.  See the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html) for more info.
4. That sets the variable `PHONY` to contain some contents.  It is just a normal variable assignment, there's nothing fancy here.  Presumably somewhere else in the makefile will appear a line: `.PHONY: $(PHONY)` and *that* will make all the targets in the `PHONY` variable phony.
5. Because the person who wrote the makefile wanted to use two underscores.